# Angular Memory Leak via DebugElement - How to run in production mode without obfuscation?

Tags: angular, memory-leaks

I am chasing a memory leak and have eliminated the usual subjects (subscriptions). When looking at the uncollected instances of my component in memory snapshots, they are all retained via paths that lead through DebugElement objects.

```
component in Object@10648105
_parentView in TemplateRef_@10653347core.js:21737
cellTemplate in Object@10684619
[24] in Array@10689419
oldValues in Object@10655939
elView in DebugContext_@10687621core.js:24015
_debugContext in DebugElement__PRE_R3__@10691153
...
```

When using `ng serve --prod`, the app still leaks memory, but I can't find the instances of my class in the snapshots anymore due to obfuscation.

Is there a way to turn off debug mode without obfuscating the code?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of an Angular CLI app in main.ts you have the following lines:

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
```

You could remove the condition to always enable prod mode.

I experienced the same, the DebugContext retaining some of the component instances. In production mode the instances were cleaned up properly.

Comment: Thank you. This allows me to look for the leak without the false positives.